# Installing Repos and DEBs from CD

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, php

I'm a Ubuntu User from 2009 and I have loved every bit of it. If it wasn't for Dreamweaver and Photoshop, I'd only use Ubuntu!
I have an Ubuntu Desktop which I want to make a DNS, DHCP, Webserver (LAMPP) and LDAP (may be). I don't want the Ubuntu Server with no GUI, i just don't like it. Love the GUI (habitual of it). I have Ubuntu Server Disk of the Same Version 12.04 LTS and Want to install above mentioned stuff from that as I have a very limited bandwidth.

Please tell me if there is anyway to do that. I have no problem with terminal usage, but I'm no expert at it!

Awaiting All you Replies!!

<Extra Info>
The Server Will be an offline Data Entry Server Software Portal with PHP apps for Intranet.
HW:

- AMD Athalon X2 2.4Ghz
- 1 GB RAM DDR2
- 320 GB SATA HDD

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How can i install debs from cd... the server cd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I Found the Answer My Self! Yay! **clapping* *
There is a 'pool' named folder in the CD/ISO that contains every DEB.
I was able to install PHP MySQL ISC-DHCP PostFix, mysql-client messed something and i had to purge it. Apache and Bind9 were giving dependency errors while installing. Not a complete Success but save my bandwidth a lot!
Most DEBs are Installable and Worth a Try!

Regards!